# Disabling use of long form when first using an acronym generated by glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

When using the acronym option of the `glossaries`-package, the first use of an acronym results in the display of

> Long Entry (Short Entry)

I want to disable this globally. I know, I could just solve this by changing my entries for every single acronym. But I don't want to do this. There has to be some kind of command to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym, shortcuts]{glossaries}      
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\newacronym{key}{Short Entry}{Long Entry}

The first use of $\backslash $ac\{key\} displays ''Long Entry (Short Entry)'', but should only display ''Short Entry''.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\backslash $` should be `\textbackslash`, or just write `\verb|\ac{key}|`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the short entry use `\acs{key}` instead. You could say `\let\ac\acs` to make `\ac` equivalent to `\acs`, but this might cause trouble. Better is to search&replace existing `\ac` with `\acs`.

Comment: As I don't want to replace every entry, I tried the redefinition and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Actually glossaries has commands for this. See Page 105 of the user manual.

The command suitable for this would be `\glsunsetall`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym, shortcuts]{glossaries}      
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\newacronym{key}{Short Entry}{Long Entry}
\glsunsetall

The first use of $\backslash $ac\{key\} displays ''Long Entry (Short Entry)'', but should only display ''Short Entry''. \ac{key}

\end{document}
```

If you would like to limit this to your acronyms glossary (for whatever reason) you could try `\glsunsetall[acronym]` or `\glsunsetall[\acronymtype]` however these resulted in not ending latex runs on my system.

To use this for single entries use `\glsunset{<key>}` or see the [manual](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) under **14 Unsetting and Resetting Entry
Flags**

Comment: Thank you! I'm reading for quite some time through the manual and didn't get how to do this. The name is pretty missleading for me.